# Recursion to get maximum difference in array

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Return a pair of numbers p and q in an array. p must appear before q in the array, and q-p must be the highest possible value

A=[1,4,12,5,9,1,3,8]

the return values would be p=1 & q=12

Someone suggested below solution. 
However I am not sure what it should return in the 'third case' as suggested below:

Suggestion:

Divide A evenly into two smaller arrays A1,A2, and solve the problem (recursively) on A1 and A2. Can that help you find the optimum on A? Don't forget you're allowed to use extra processing costing up to O(n).Suppose that p,q is the optimal pair for A. Either p,q∈A1, or p,q∈A2, or neither of these cases is true. What can you say in the third case about p and q?

Below is my code where it basically divides the array and get the minimum from first half and maximum from second half. There is 0(n) solution for this but i am interested in the recursive one as i am learning the recursion. So please don't suggest any other solution.

```
    #define min_f(a, b) (a)>(b)?(b):(a)
    #define max_f(a, b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b)
    #define MAX 1 << 30
    #define MIN -1

    int get_min(int *a, int start, int end)
    {
            int t_min = MAX;
            while(start <= end) {
                    t_min = min_f(t_min, a[start]);
                    start++;
            }
            return t_min;
    }

    int get_max(int *a, int start, int end)
    {
            int t_max = MIN;
            while(start <= end) {
                    t_max = max_f(t_max, a[start]);
                    start++;
            }
            return t_max;
    }

    int foo(int *a, int start, int end)
    {
            int g_max = MIN;
            int min, max, i;

            for(i=0;i<=end;i++) {
                    min = get_min(a, start, i);
                    max = get_max(a, i+1, end);
                    if (max > min) {
                            g_max = max_f(g_max, max-min);
                    }
            }
            return g_max;
    }

    int main()
    {
            int a[] = {1,4,12,5,9,1,3,8};
            int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
            printf("%d\n", foo(a, 0, size-1));
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: @mikeb: why do you think that? I really dislike people who don't ask questions and assume (ass u & me). http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14665/create-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/14668#14668

Comment: No, I won't remove it, because even if it is not "homework" you should try to figure it out on your own and come here when you get stuck.  You are coming here trying to get someone to do it for you, instead of at least making an effort.  Take a stab at the solution and I'll not only remove the -1, I'll help you figure it out.  If this is too difficult a problem, perhaps you should solve something simpler, like a function taking a number n and return fibonacci(n).  This is a classic recursion problem and should get you started.

Comment: I have read what you wrote.  You are giving us apples and asking us to create oranges from it.  You have not even tried.  I didn't copy-paste, lol.  If you don't at least *attempt* to do what you want nobody is going to write your assignment for you. What have you tried so far?  Where is your example code that is supposed to do what you want but is not giving you the expected results?  Don't just paste some working code an ask someone to convert it.  Post some broken code and ask for some tips on how to fix it, then you might get some help.

Comment: @mikeb: this is my last comment to make you _understand_ that i am not looking for code but rather the idea. I just want to know what is the "third case" when the p and q both are not good in sub divided array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive solution is nothing but a [Divide and Conquer algorithm.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDivide_and_conquer_algorithms&ei=q2eFVfTtG82UuASm-YRg&usg=AFQjCNEczP5BTlPCLFEl43SPtkb-oyzBDA&sig2=Xnzrdqfzbut80GaMxBPuHQ&bvm=bv.96339352,d.c2E) You can also look-up [Binary-search algorithm](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/) to understand the basic concept of Divide and Conquer.

Now, let us take your example.

```
                 [1,4,12,5,9,1,3,8]
                       /\
                      /  \
                     /    \
            [1,4,12,5]    [9,1,3,8]
```

If you did read the above link, or you know the Divide and Conquer algorithm, you will understand that we recursively do the operation for the left sub-array and the right-subarray. The next step is, we divide each of the halves again. Here, lets just do the first half, it would be sufficient to get to the third case, which you are clueless about.

Take the first half, to divide it again.

```
                  [1,4,12,5]
                     /\
                    /  \
                   /    \
              [1,4]      [12,5]
```

At this step of dividing the array, you should have understood what the third case is. The answer p = 1 (in left-half) and q = 12(in right-half) lie in **different halves after division**

This was the third case. Now, I leave it up to you to write the recursive code for this and take care of the third case appropriately in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can find maximum value first in an recursion function, then find the minimum value at the same way. After you can find the differance. I don't think that you can make it by one function.

```
 public static int diff(int[] arr)
    {
        int max=findMax(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
        int min=findMin(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);

        return max-min;
    }

 private static int findMax(int[] arr, int index_begin, int index_end)
    {
        if (index_begin == index_end) return arr[index_begin];

        int m = (index_begin + index_end) / 2;

        return Math.Max(findMax(arr, index_begin, m), findMax(arr, m + 1, 
        index_end));
    }
 private static int findMin(int[] arr, int index_begin, int index_end)
    {
        if (index_begin == index_end) return arr[index_begin];

        int m = (index_begin + index_end) / 2;

        return Math.Min( findMin(arr, index_begin, m), findMin(arr, m + 1, 
        index_end));
    }
```